# Email Problem while add attachment file

Tags: php, email

I have problem while i try to send email with attachment file, i just get message with blank attachment, how i can fix it. Here is my code:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF("P","A4", "fr");
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
$to = "example@yahoo.com"; 
$subject = "Voucher Mediskon";
$random_hash = md5(date("r", time()));
$headers = "From: Admin Mediskon<admin@" . $domain . ">\r\nReply-To: admin@" . $domain;
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode( $html2pdf->Output("", "S") ));
ob_start();
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Terimakasih telah membeli voucher kami. Mediskon</h2>
<p>Silakan <b>unduh ( download )</b> voucher pada <b>attachment</b> yang kami kirim.</p>
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="voucher.pdf" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 
<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?php 
$message = ob_get_clean();
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: Maybe clean up your post a little, it's pretty hard to read as-is.

Comment: If this is not for the purpose of learning how MIME mail works, consider using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PHP's mail function directly. It is insecure and inflexible. Plus you are reinventing the wheel. Here are two great email libraries that support HTML and file attachments:

- [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)
- [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

Comment: I disagree, its very flexible - and hence allows people to write insecure code using it. Certainly if you don't know what you're doing these wrappers can make life a bit less dangerous.

Comment: Hmmm. By inflexible I meant that the API was inadequate for adding attachments etc. Yes you can just pipe anything you like into `mail()`, but it is easy to be tripped up.

Comment: Maybe i will use mail function for simple email and it's great to learning about it..

Comment: I try your advice using SwiftMailer and it's good and looks like I will use it for long time..

Answer (score 1):

> i just get message with blank attachment

So the problem is not with the email, nor is with the process of attaching the file to the email.

Have you looked at the raw data in the message to see if the attachment is null length?

Have you tried writing the generated PDF to a file to check its contents?

Comment: yes i do it but sometimes i don't get attachment at all...
so I have conclusion there is mistake in my code...
could you fix it or my code is right or no wrong in my code...